# Child process not reading from pipe, unless parent calls printf before dup2

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup2

The code below forks a child process, and redirects stdout to the pipe. The child is supposed to read from the pipe but it's not happening. Strangely, if the parent is made to call printf at least once before calling dup2, things seem to work. I guess that's a luck not to be relied upon... but an explanation would be still great. More importantly, why is the child not able to read?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2]; 
    pid_t p;
   
    if(pipe(fd) == -1) 
        return -1;
    
    if((p=fork()) == -1)
        return -1;

    if(p==0){
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0],0);
        fprintf(stderr,"Child starts\n");
        int x;
        scanf("%d",&x);                   // GETS STUCK HERE
        fprintf(stderr,"Child ends\n");  
        exit(0);
    }

    // printf(" ");        // THIS PRINTF SEEMS TO RESOLVE THE ISSUE?!  

    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1],1);
    printf("3\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Parent waiting\n");
    wait(0);
    fprintf(stderr, "Parent ends\n");
}
```

Lots of questions have been asked on `fork` and `pipe` but I could not find an answer to my problem. Apologies if it is a duplicate question.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent `stdout` is *not* line buffered (because it becomes a pipe). So, the data that `printf("3\n");` outputs stays in the stream's *buffer* and is *not* flushed to the pipe.

There are two ways to fix this (in the parent):

1. add `setlinebuf(stdout);` immediately before that `printf`
2. add `fflush(stdout);` immediately after that `printf`

---

**UPDATE:**

> And adding the extra printf() fixes it why? I suppose that at that point, the underlying file descriptor for standard output is still a terminal so it puts the stream into line-buffered mode, and that doesn't change when the underlying file descriptor is changed to a pipe. –
> Jonathan Leffler

Yes, that is correct. If we change:

```
printf(" ");
```

Into:

```
setlinebuf(stdout);
```

Then, that also works.

(i.e.) the `printf` to a real tty [implicitly] set line buffered mode.

The probe/test for output is a tty device is [obviously] deferred until something active is done with the device (e.g. `printf`)

The `dup2` is transparent to the stream so the stream's flags stay the same.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Is it possible to handle it from the child side?

No, the child has a different *memory space* from the parent. It starts out as a copy of the parent's memory. But, it is independent. Changes to it do *not* affect the parent's memory (or vice versa).

More on this below. But, remember that the child is waiting for a number which is a digit string followed by whitespace. The whitespace here is a newline.

> For example, what if the parent execv's a different program whose output is to be read by the child? –
> cobra

We have to be careful with terminology.

"parent/child" is a concept of `fork` but *not* `execv`. So, when doing the `execv` in the *parent* we are *not* talking about *the* child (or *any* child). We are talking about the "target program" of the exec.

The target program has the same issue as before.

Streams are a userspace/application concept. The OS kernel has *no* knowledge of them. The kernel only knows "file descriptors". Things that come from `open`, `pipe`, `socket`, etc.

`stdio` streams are just a buffering mechanism for I/O. They exist *only* in a given process's memory. They are an "efficiency" mechanism to prevent excessive/repeated/wasteful syscalls (i.e. `write` calls) for small amounts of data.

The concept of "line buffering" is just a flag (and the action it takes) inside a stream struct. TTY output devices default to line buffering--the buffer is flushed when it sees a newline.

Other things like files (or *pipes* ;-) default to "standard" buffering (e.g. 4096 bytes). They are flushed when the 4096 is exceeded. "Flushing" means that the `stdio` layer writes to the underlying file descriptor (via the `write` syscall).

When an `execv` is done, the memory is completely replaced and loaded from the target program's executable file contents.

The target program gets control and its `crt0.o` initialization code runs. It must create `stdin/stdout/stderr` from scratch, without regard to what these *may* have been in the memory space before the `execv` (which no longer exists)

So, by the time the `main` function of the target program gets control, `stdout` is attached to the pipe.

It has the same buffering issue. In fact, the `printf(" ")` done before would have *no* effect on the state of the target's `stdout` stream.

The target would *never* see `stdout` (FD 1) as a TTY. It has *already* been set up as a pipe (so it gets standard buffering). The only remedy would be to use `setlinebuf` or do periodic `fflush` calls.

If that program *just* outputs data to `stdout` and then terminates, the `stdout` stream (if the target even uses stdio at all) is flushed on exit.

Otherwise, the target program has the same issues as the original program.

The programmer is expected to know they are dealing with a pipe (because they set it up) and handle the buffering accordingly.

Comment: And adding the extra `printf()` fixes it why?  I suppose that at that point, the underlying file descriptor for standard output is still a terminal so it puts the stream into line-buffered mode, and that doesn't change when the underlying file descriptor is changed to a pipe.

Comment: Is it possible to handle it from the child side? For example, what if the parent `execv`'s a different program whose output is to be read by the child?